# How to define routePrefix in yaml with container parameter?

Tags: api-platform.com

Api resources don't work with routePrefix configuration if I configure it like this:

```yaml
# config/api_platform/resources/product.yaml
resources:
  '%app.entity.product.class%':
    ...
    routePrefix: '%app.routePrefix%'
```

In configurations, injected from my bundle to container, I have something like this (I've simplified it all to describe my problem):

```yaml
app:
  entity:
    product:
      class: App\Entity\Product
  routePrefix: 'pim2'
```

In swagger everything seems OK, I see my routes with desired prefix, but if I run some route I get an error:

```
\<!-- Operation "\_api_pim2/products{.\_format}\_get_collection" not found for resource "Product". (500 Internal Server Error) --\>
```

Command `symfony console debug:api App\\Entity\\Product` output contains the rows below:

- #class: "App\Entity\Product"
- #routePrefix: "%app.routePrefix%"

I don't understand, why it works with `class`, but fails on `routePrefix`. How can I fix this bug?